# TP Link 722N not recognized by Kali or any other Linux based system I tried

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux

I already have the extension pack on virtualbox enabled. I also created a filter so the usb IS enabled. And whenever I start up kali nothing shows on `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`

I did type `lsusb` and it shows on there

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:010c  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It's the second one with the ID 2357.

Output of `dmesg`

```
[  134.763959] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  140.510355] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  140.835736] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=010c
[  140.835738] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, 
SerialNumber=3
[  140.835739] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  140.835739] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  140.835740] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00E07C4271
[  334.471555] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  340.246635] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  340.571596] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=010c
[  340.571598] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, 
SerialNumber=3
[  340.571599] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  340.571600] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  340.571600] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00E07C4271
```

I tried adding `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free` to my sources.list and typing `apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-atheros` but nothing has been really installed/upgraded.

As you can see it's recognized, but doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 versions of TP-Link WN722N:

- V1 (supports monitor mode and packet injection)

  Comes with Atheros9271 chipset, which is almost plug-n-play in Kali.
- V2 (doesnt support both)

  Comes with Realtek RTL8188, which will cause You a lot of problems.

If you can, return V2 and find V1 on ebay or in shops (check model number on the bottom of the box)

#### Version comparsion:

https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN722N